# Geração de Boletos com Bopepo

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, boleto

Tenho um sistema que gera um contas a receber, e estou tentando implementar a geração de boletos bancários, meu professor Orientador me indicou a ferramenta 'Bopepo' Jrmum. Inseri no meu sistema e consegui gerar um boleto de exemplo, porem quero passar as informações para o boleto por parâmetro conforme o usuário digitar.. alguém já usou essa ferramenta ou sabe como fazer isso ? 
Aguardo resposta,
Obrigado.

```
 final Titulo crieOsDadosDoNovoTitulo(Titulo titulo) {

    /*
     * DADOS BÁSICOS.
     */
    titulo.setNumeroDoDocumento("12345");
    titulo.setNossoNumero("00234569812345");
    titulo.setDigitoDoNossoNumero("5");
    titulo.setValor(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.23));

    // Para informar a data de maneira simples você pode utilizar as 
    // classes utilitárias do JRimum. Abaixo temos alguns exemplos:
    // (1) titulo.setDataDoVencimento(  DateFormat.DDMMYYYY_B.parse("11/03/2011")  );
    // (2) titulo.setDataDoVencimento(  Dates.parse("11/03/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy")  );     
    titulo.setDataDoDocumento(new Date());
    titulo.setDataDoVencimento(new Date());

    titulo.setTipoDeDocumento(TipoDeTitulo.DM_DUPLICATA_MERCANTIL);
    titulo.setAceite(Aceite.A);
    titulo.setDesconto(new BigDecimal(0.05));
    titulo.setDeducao(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    titulo.setMora(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    titulo.setAcrecimo(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    titulo.setValorCobrado(BigDecimal.ZERO);

    return titulo;
}
```

Comment: Pode postar o seu código aí para dar um ponto de partida mais seguro e firme para quem for responder a sua pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei um trecho na descrição, a parte dos valores. essa classe é a classe de exemplo do Bopepo, e eu tenho minha classe de contas a receber. Preciso substituir esses valores

Comment: Vez que você está usando JSF (a julgar pela tag), eu apenas iria salvando essas informações dentro de um managed bean e colocaria um botão "gerar boleto". Ao clicar neste botão, ele faria a validação, e caso tudo esteja certo, executaria esse seu método aí pegando as informações armazenadas no managed bean para gerar o boleto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, Leandro.

Eu criei uma classe de transporte (na qual eu coleto os dados que preciso emitir no BD) e a partir dela e de mais algumas informações eu emito o boleto.

A emissão dos boletos no Bopepo tem algumas pegadinhas que você vai descobrindo nos testes (uma vez que a documentação não é suficiente). Por exemplo: 1) CPF ou CNPJ do Sacado tem que ser válido (muitas vezes eu não tenho essa informação). 2) As instruções tem que ser preenchidas ainda que com string vazia (""). 3) DV da conta corrente e do boleto tem que ser fornecidos separadamente). Etc.

Amanhã pela manhã, vou limpar o código e publico para você dar uma olhada.

Não foi difícil sair do zero e emitir um boleto, ainda que com dados fake.

Comment: Ok estou aguardando o código pois tenho que ter um exemplo se não eu não consigo e só falta isso praticamente isso para finalizar meu TCC rs estou com muita dificuldade nessa parte.